# getStaticPaths - data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js, strapi

I am using Strapi with Next.js for my blog project

I am trying to make dynamic pages by using [id].js inside pages/posts/[id].js

But, the problem is when I try to map through the API of Strapi inside getStaticPaths() it gives me an error with data.map is not defined

Note:- I am using NextJS V12.0.8 with Strapi V4.0.4

Below is my code

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const postsRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/posts?populate=image");
 
  const paths = postsRes.map((post) => {
    return { params: {id: post.id.toString()} }
  });

  // const paths = { params: {id: '1' } }
    
  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
 
  }
 
}
```

Complete `[id].js` Page Code Link - https://pastebin.com/SnzLirys

Error Screenshot - https://prnt.sc/26ha6z5

Comment: Did you mean to call `postsRes.data.map()` instead?

Comment: did you try looking at the [docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema)? `axios.get` returns a `Response` object. The data you are looking for can be found at `postsRes.data`

Comment: @juliomalves   Thanks for your replay, Yes I have also tried it but still it gives the same error  ---- > https://prnt.sc/26hh5pa

Comment: @derpirscher Yes I know that it returns an object response as I have made my blog front page using axios ----> https://prnt.sc/26hh75z

Comment: well, then `postRes.data` is not an array but nobody can help you beyond that point, because we don't know what `postRes.data` really is ...

Comment: Actually, I am following this tutorial  ---> https://youtu.be/599ogMbXIyA?t=5252  with timelapse

Comment: Might be, but maybe you made an error at the server side? Nobody will go through this entire video to find out what `postRes.data` is supposed to be (probably an array, because otherwise it wouldn't work in the tutorial). And furthermore nobody knows, what you are actually returning from the backend of this request ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241307/discussion-between-owaiz-yusufi-and-derpirscher).

Comment: If `postRes.data` isn't returning the expected response then either you're not making the request properly or the API endpoint isn't returning the expected response. Do you see any errors in the terminal from the API call? Are you sure `/api/posts?populate=image` is handling the request as intended? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @juliomalves yes I have tested the API using postman

Comment: @juliomalves you can download the project from my github repo -> https://github.com/Yusufzai/strapi-next-blog

Answer (score 8):

All you needed to do is restart the npm run dev
by pressing ctrl + c
then re running the dev

Answer (score 2):

apparently you need to set up a context to use axios inside that function, or you can try to format the axios response to json.stringfy and then use json.parse in it. or just use fetch.

in case you are using next api folder, don't call fetch or axios here, just make the query as if you were in node

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
      const get = await fetch("url")
      const data = await get.json()
      
      data.map(item => console.log(item))
     
      const paths = data.map((post) => {
        return { params: {id: post.id.toString()} }
      });
    
      // const paths = { params: {id: '1' } }
        
      return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
     
      }
     
    }
```